# DatagramSocket can send broadcast packets on phone, but not on PC

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, uwp

I have this weird problem with a datagram socket. Basically what I am doing is building a class that allows my app to announce the services it implements and discover other instances on the same network and their services.
I use the DatagramSocket class to broadcast a packet to 255.255.255.255 and other apps on the network would respond to it.
This works perfectly when the app on the phone is trying to discover the one on desktop. But the app on desktop can't discover the one on my phone.
I ran wireshark to monitor the packets and the phone is sending the packets as expected, but the desktop app doesn't send any packets.
I am trying to find out if there is a reason why the app fails to send broadcast packets from my desktop but is capable of doing so when it is running from my phone?

I have tested my code with Windows Firewall turned on and off (only firewall I am using).

Devices I have tested this on are:

- Lumia 950XL (Win10 V1607 Build 14393) - can broadcast
- Surface Book (Win10 1607 Build 14393) - can't broadcast
- HP AIO (Win10 1607 Build 14393) - can't broadcast

Here is the code I am using to broadcast packets:

```
            if (this.datagramSocket == null)
        {
            //initialize the datagram object
            this.datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();

            //handle the message received event
            this.datagramSocket.MessageReceived += DatagramSocket_MessageReceived;

            //bind the datagram to a service name / port
            await this.datagramSocket.BindServiceNameAsync(this.finderPort.ToString());
        }

        //get an output stream to write the ping message to
        using (var outputStream = await this.datagramSocket.GetOutputStreamAsync(new HostName(BroadcastAddress), this.advertiserPort.ToString()))
        {

            using (var writer = new DataWriter(outputStream))
            {
                //write the message like[id],[name]
                writer.WriteString("Very Special Message");

                //commit everything to the stream
                await writer.StoreAsync();
            }
        }
```

the 'advertiserPort' and 'finderPort' are predefined as '1994' and '2206' respectively. the 'BroadcastAddress' is 255.255.255.255

Edit: I also tried the DatagramSocket sample provided by Microsoft with the same results. The sample fails to broadcast anything when running on PC and wireshark shows no packets being sent.

Comment: You should be listening for the packets using IPAny with the correct port number.

Comment: @jdweng can you explain more? I followed the UWP sample provided by MS. even that sample doesn't work.

Comment: IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1994);

Comment: @jdweng there is no method in DatagramSocket that accepts IPEndPoint object as a parameter. Also, this exact code works find on a Mobile device (Lumia 950xl running latest public Win10 version).

Comment: Did you try localhost and Port Number?

Comment: @jdweng using 'localhost' throws the following exception:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The requested address is not valid in its context.

Comment: I'm curious if you can from cmd.exe >ping localhost.  You can also use IP instead of computer name.  So use loopback IP 127.0.0.1.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.endpointpair

Comment: yes I can, but how does this help in fixing the inability to send broadcast messages?

Comment: Try making subnet mask 0.0.0.0 to allow all IP to be sent.  You can check the mask from cmd.exe using >IPCONIFG/ALL.  If the mask is set you will only be able to send IP within the mask range.

Comment: @jdweng thank you for the follow up but making such changes does nothing. I tested the code on multiple devices and multiple networks all with the same result: works on mobile, fails on desktop.

Comment: See webpage : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/72e7387a-9f2c-4bf4-a004-c89ddde1c8aa/how-to-fix-the-global-broadcast-address-255255255255-behavior-on-windows?forum=w7itpronetworking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally solved the problem. For some unknown reason, `DatagramSocket` can send UDP packets to global broadcast address (255.255.255.255) when running on a phone, but fails to do so when running on a PC. However, using directed broadcast address (192.168.1.255 for example) works fine on both platforms.

Problem is, UWP only has API to get global broadcast address and if you want to get the directed broadcast address for your current network, you will need to calculate it.

for the benefit of everyone here I will share the code to calculate that address, and hopefully MS will fix this.

this method helps with getting the subnet mask for the network from the device IP address:

```
public static IPAddress GetSubnetMask(IPAddress hostAddress)
    {
        var addressBytes = hostAddress.GetAddressBytes();

        if (addressBytes[0] >= 1 && addressBytes[0] <= 126)
            return IPAddress.Parse("255.0.0.0");
        else if (addressBytes[0] >= 128 && addressBytes[0] <= 191)
            return IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.0");
        else if (addressBytes[0] >= 192 && addressBytes[0] <= 223)
            return IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.0");
        else
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
```

This method is the one that will give the Directed broadcast address:

```
        public static IPAddress GetBroadastAddress(IPAddress hostIPAddress)
    {
        var subnetAddress = GetSubnetMask(hostIPAddress);

        var deviceAddressBytes = hostIPAddress.GetAddressBytes();
        var subnetAddressBytes = subnetAddress.GetAddressBytes();

        if (deviceAddressBytes.Length != subnetAddressBytes.Length)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

        var broadcastAddressBytes = new byte[deviceAddressBytes.Length];

        for (var i = 0; i < broadcastAddressBytes.Length; i++)
            broadcastAddressBytes[i] = (byte)(deviceAddressBytes[i] | subnetAddressBytes[i] ^ 255);

        return new IPAddress(broadcastAddressBytes);
    }
```

Again, I don't have any idea on why there is such difference in the behavior of the same API while running on different device families, but hopefully this code will help someone out there.